# How to Resolve Keyword Error with SAS Macro

Tags: macros, sas, params-keyword

I'm running this sql macro in SAS.

```
%macro calc(table=,cut=,whereclause=);
proc sql;
&table
   select 
        &cut as type format = $40. length = 40
       ,dt
       ,count(prod_nbr) as stat
       ,sum(new) as new
       ,sum(old) as old
       ,sum(retired) as retired
       ,sum(replaced) as replaced
       ,sum(final) as final
       ,sum(redo) as redo

from work.product
where retail_flg = 1
&whereclause
group by 1,2;
quit;
%mend calc;
```

I call the macro about sixty times in the program and it works about 80% of the time when I call it.  But every once and a while it will generate this error:
`ERROR: All positional parameters must precede keyword parameters`

If I run the code in the same order, the error always shows at the same line.  But if I start running the calls in different orders the error will eventually occur on a seemingly random line of code that calls the macro.  Here is an example of one of the calls that it gets caught up on (after calc table has already been created):

```
%calc(table = insert into calc, cut = 'Product', whereclause = and brand = 'JNJ' and Prod_type = 'N' and index(prod_nm, 'NEW') > 0);
```

I'm especially confused by the error since I don't have any positional parameters in the macro.  I've researched and trouble shot for syntax errors and other common issues without being able to resolve the error.

Comment: How are you calling it multiple times? Via some other macro? Call Execute?

Comment: I'm just running multiple lines of code like the one above.  For example:
%calc(table = insert into calc, cut = 'Product', whereclause = and brand = 'JNJ' );
%calc(table = insert into calc, cut = 'New Produce', whereclause = and brand = 'WMT' and Prod_type = 'Q');

Comment: So you are typing them by hand?

Comment: @Tom Yes.  I've only been using SAS for 3 months.  That's the only way I know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have unbalanced quotes somewhere. Perhaps some value you have the the WHERECLAUSE has unbalanced quotes. I would look at the value BEFORE the one that generates the error message.  It might also be the result of code being truncated.  For example if you are writing the generated code to a file some long WHERECLAUSE value might get truncated and result in unbalanced quotes.

Adding some extra line breaks in your macro calls can make it easier to check for errors since shorter lines are easier for humans to scan.

```
%calc
(table = insert into calc
,cut = 'Product'
,whereclause =
  and brand = 'JNJ' and Prod_type = 'N'
  and index(prod_nm, 'NEW') > 0
);
```

Comment: In my trouble shooting I did every once and a while see a warning about truncation.  Why would SAS truncate my WHERECLAUSE and how can I prevent it from happening?

Comment: It depends on how you are submitting your code.  If you are using the SAS Display Manager editor there are limits on how long a line of code the editor can handle.

Comment: I think this is my problem.  I'm looking for some work arounds to this issue.  Do you have any solutions to the lines of code being too long?

Comment: Just put some more line breaks in the code. As long you are don't put them in the middle of quoted strings or keywords it shouldn't matter.

Comment: That was it! A very simple solution.  I'd been trouble shooting all sorts of things for hours.  thanks!